# Help understanding a full wave bridge rectifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes, oscilloscope, rectifier

I'm trying to understand the workings of a full wave bridge rectifier and would like some help. The output I got is shown below, and I'm wondering with a 6.3V rms input, why is the output amplitude so much less than this? Is there a way to calculate this amplitude?

Additionally, why are there flat spaces between each of the waves? Where do these flat spaces come from?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram, and show the points where you are making the measurement. (hit Ctrl-M to open the schematic editor)

Comment: Are you sure that's 6.3V rms? What you have there is closer to what I'd expect to see if you had 6.3V peak.

Comment: Flat spaces are when voltage gets below 0.7V and -0.7V, respectively.

Comment: needs capacitors to get the most out...

Answer (score 3):

Both of your questions are answered by this simple fact: When a diode is conducting, it will have a voltage drop across it. For your standard silicon diode (1N4148, 1N4001, etc), this is somewhere around 0.5~0.7V under normal conditions (it increases slightly at high currents). For Schottky diodes, it's closer to 0.2~0.3V, germanium diodes are around 0.3~0.4V, and very high power diodes can be very high, up to multiple volts or even tens of volts.

Since in a bridge rectifier, two diodes are conducting at any one time, you'll be losing two diode drops worth of voltage; this explains your reduced voltage. The flat bits are a consequence of this as well: if there isn't enough voltage to turn the diodes on, they simply won't conduct.